# Can this SQL query be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

This is a query for a Postfix table lookup (smtpd_sender_login_maps) in MariaDB (MySQL). Given an email address it returns the users allowed to use that address. I am using two SQL tables to store accounts and aliases that need to be searched. Postfix requires a single query to return a single result set hence the `UNION SELECT`. I know there is `unionmap:{}` in postfix but i do not want to go that route and prefer the union select. The `emails.email` column is the username that is returned for Postfix SASL authentication. The `%s` in the query is where Postfix inserts the email address to search for. The reason for matching everything back to the `emails.postfixPath` is because that is the physical inbox, if two accounts share the same inbox they should both have access to use all the same emails including aliases.

```
Table: emails
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| email       | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| postfixPath | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| password    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| acceptMail  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| allowLogin  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| mgrLogin    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

.

```
Table: aliases
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| email      | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| forwardTo  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| acceptMail | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

.

```
SELECT email
    FROM emails
    WHERE postfixPath=(
        SELECT postfixPath
            FROM emails
            WHERE email='%s'
            AND acceptMail=1
            LIMIT 1)
    AND password IS NOT NULL
    AND allowLogin=1
UNION SELECT email
    FROM emails
    WHERE postfixPath=(
        SELECT postfixPath
            FROM emails
            WHERE email=(
                SELECT forwardTo 
                    FROM aliases 
                    WHERE email='%s' 
                    AND acceptMail=1)
            LIMIT 1)
    AND password IS NOT NULL
    AND allowLogin=1
    AND acceptMail=1
```

This query works, it just looks heavy to me and i feel like it should be more streamlined / efficient. Does anyone have a better way to write this or is this as good as it gets?

- I added `CREATE INDEX index_postfixPath ON emails (postfixPath)` per @The Impaler's suggestion.

@Rick James here is the additional table info:

```
Table: emails
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `emails` (
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`postfixPath` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`acceptMail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`allowLogin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`mgrLogin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
KEY `index_postfixPath` (`postfixPath`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Table: aliases
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `aliases` (
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`forwardTo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`acceptMail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

.

Comment: The query is in good shape to be optimized.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, are you saying it needs to be optimized, or you saying it is already optimized?

Comment: Dear God, not plain-text passwords :(

Comment: No not plain text, they are hashed, i left size (50) instead of sizing it to exact hash size in case i change the hash type in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

```
SELECT  email
    FROM  emails
    WHERE  postfixPath=
    (
        SELECT  postfixPath
            FROM  emails
            WHERE  email='%s'
              AND  acceptMail = 1
            LIMIT  1
    )
      AND  password IS NOT NULL
      AND  allowLogin = 1
```

With indexes:

```
emails: (email, acceptMail, password)
```

I assume `acceptMail` has only 2 values?  The Optimizer cannot know that, so it sees `AND acceptMail` as a range test.  `AND acceptMail = 1` fixes that.  (No, `> 0`, `!= 0`, etc, can't be optimized.)

Part 2:

This has 3 layers, and is probably where the inefficiency is.

```
SELECT e.email
    FROM ( SELECT forwardTo ... ) AS c
    JOIN ( SELECT postfixPath ... ) AS d ON ...
    JOIN emails AS e  ON e.postfixPath = d.postfixPath
```

This is how the Optimizer *might* optimize your version.  But I am not sure it did, so I changed it to encourage it to do so.

Again, use `=1` when testing for "true".  Then have these indexes:

```
aliases:  (email, acceptMail, forwardTo)
emails:   (email, postfixPath)
emails:   (postfixPath, allowLogin, acceptMail, password, email)
```

Finally, the `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... part 1 ... )
UNION ALL 
( SELECT ... part 2 ... )
```

I added parentheses to avoid ambiguities about what clauses belong to the Selects versus to the Union.

`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` (which is `UNION DISTINCT`), but you might get the same email twice.  However, that may be nonsense -- forwarding an email to yourself??

The order of columns in each index is important.  (However, *some* variants are equivalent.)

I think all the indexes I provided are "covering", thereby giving an extra performance boost.

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  "MUL" is especially ambiguous.

(Caveat:  I threw this code together rather hastily; it may not be quite correct, but principles should help.)

For further optimization, please do like I did in splitting it into 3 steps.  Check the performance of each.

Comment: I added the table info you suggested in the above original post.

Comment: Yes, i also don't like the 3 layers in the 2nd select. My intent in posting this was to see if someone could figure out an entirely different way to structure this query, like maybe a creative table join using only one select to get the same result. Im not married to the current syntax.

Comment: And yes, Im using all of the tiny-int's as booleans and only setting true/false (1/0).

Comment: @Private_Citizen - You have 2 tables, each with `PRIMARY KEY(email)`.  It would probably be better to simply combine the tables.  Is there an argument for keeping them separate?

Comment: No technical argument, just the logical separation of these are accounts and these are aliases, which could go offsite and not even to an account. Plus it would be ugly IMO having an account row inserted just to put alias=this.email. I would have to add two more columns to the emails table. And not sure yet if that would simplify the query or not because i would still have to return results from two columns (email or forwardTo). Your thoughts?

Comment: I have tried twice to (at) you Rick James but each time i do it removes it from my post, i assume it has to do with the space in your name. What is the correct syntax/way?

Comment: About your comment of two tables both with KEY(email), although named the same one is an account name which also happens to be the email address and one is an alias email address. If i used the same column for both id have to have a column saying if that "email" is an account with an inbox (maildir/) or just an alias, which in the end i think would still require two queries because depending on if its an account or alias would have different matching criteria.

Comment: (The site removes the space; it's fine.)

Comment: @Private_Citizen - OK, I guess I was sidetracked by the PK.  I described a restructuring; did it help?

Answer (score 0):

The following three indexes will make the query faster:

```
create index ix1 on emails (allowLogin, postfixPath, acceptMail, password, email);

create index ix2 on emails (email, acceptMail);

create index ix3 on aliases (email, acceptMail);
```

Comment: I see what you saying. Wouldn't it be better to only index postfixPath then reverse order looking for postfixPath first then check bool conditions vs adding all those indexes. I will edit the query showing this.

Comment: @Private_Citizen It depends if you want the engine to use the index for access purposes only, or for filtering and covering purposes as well. Your option will provide you some level of performance improvement, but the indexes I included are close to optimal. Nevertheless they are more expensive. I would suggest to try both options and measure them.

Comment: `ix1` starts with a "range", (`IS NOT NULL`) so the rest is not useful.  Move it to later in the index.